# Saving the name of an element in a list R

Tags: r

I have a somewhat large list of paragraphs called `psw_list` short for paragraphs separated by word:

`c("For", "more", "than", "five", "years,", "William", "Sencion",  "did", "the", "same", "task", "over", "and", "over.", "He", "signed",  "onto", "the", "New", "York", "City’s", "housing", "lottery",  "site", "and", "applied", "for", "one", "of", "the", "city’s",  "highly", "coveted,", "below-market", "apartments.", "Each",  "time,", "he", "got", "the", "same", "response:", "silence.")`

I'm only including the first paragraph because they're all this length, but I have each paragraph labeled as p1, p2, p3, etc. in the list, so you can reference it by using `psw_list$p1` to get this one specifically. I need to save the name of a paragraph, for example `psw_list$p1`, inside of a loop that will randomly select a paragraph from the entire psw_list, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Sample the list names: `n <- sample(names(psw_list), 1); psw_list[[n]]`

Comment: You can also directly do `sample(psw_list, n)` which gets a list of n (could be 1) randomly selected elements of the list.

Comment: @Roland So i've been using sample and have a pretty good grasp of that but do you know a way of saving the p name so that i can refer to in the same loop? I'm trying to replace words within each paragraph and save the new word in the old words specific place in that paragraph

Comment: In the example given by @Roland the name is stored in the variable `n` , so you would do `psw_to_work_on <- psw_list[[n]];` then change `psw_to_work_on` however you like and write it back like `psw_list[[n]] <- psw_to_work_on` . Alternatively, you could modify one word in place if you know its index by doing `psw_list[[n]][i] <- replacement_word`

Comment: @AllanCameron dude thank you so much

Comment: @AllanCameron is there a way to randomly select a word in that psw_list to get `psw_list[[n]][i] ` and modify it from there? because I don't know the specific index.

Comment: @djc1223 you can get a random `i` with `i <- sample(length(psw_list[[n]]), 1)`